# AX 2012 R2 Real-time Service Profile setup form refuses to accept Passphrase

Tags: real-time, installation, profile, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to setup a Real-time Service (previously called Transaction Service in R1) profile in Dynamics AX 2012 R2.  This is a test environment, with the Real-time Service installed on the AOS machine. The scripts to deploy the server certificate & commerce data exchange real time service have succeeded.  I am following the steps on this site: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/axsupport/archive/2012/12/18/ax-for-retail-2012-r2-installing-the-real-time-service.aspx
... as well as MS's documentation "Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 Installation Guide" and "Implementation guide for Commerce Data Exchange"

Unfortunately, while creating a Real time service profile, AX does not accept any Passphrase that I enter.  The info log shows the following error message:

"Please enter a new password when creating a new Real-time Service profile."

As per the Microsoft support documents, the passphrase value must be something, but it doesn't matter what it is.  The passphrase is automatically synced with the RTS and the POS clients via the CDE services and is only used for authenticating  the communication between the POS & AOS via the RTS.

Thanks in advance for any help and advice.

djz

P.S. One other odd thing to note: After entering a new Passphrase and tabbing out of the field, when I first click Close on the form, nothing happens.  (i.e., the Close button depresses, but the form stays open, nothing is saved, and no error message appears.)  The second time I click the Close button is when the error message appears.  Personally I think the form is buggy.

P.P.S. I have tried numerous Google searches for this error and they all reference the same forum post, and the only answer given is "have you followed the directions on this web site?" (i.e., http://blogs.msdn.com/b/axsupport/archive/2012/12/18/ax-for-retail-2012-r2-installing-the-real-time-service.aspx)

e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852740/error-while-creating-real-time-service-profile-on-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to be an issue I've encountered in AX 2012 R2 too.
In fact, retail parameters wasn't set for Realtime Service password encryption (RetailSharedParameters.TSPasswordEncryption).

In order to set it, you can just go to Retail > Setup > Parameters > Retail parameters
Then clic on 'Initialize' button to set the basic retail parameters (RTS encryption, distibution programs, etc...).

Then it should be OK.

Regards,
Geoffrey